# Theme Hospital Resolution stuck at 640x480

Tags: windows-xp, virtualization, theme-hospital

I've installed my old trusty Bullfrog "Theme Hospital", the 2002 version inside a Windows XP virtual machine. The game works well, but is stuck in 640x480 resolution as in the following image:

[image: Stuck in 640x480 resolution]

This results in a huge border around the game and makes the game harder to play. The listing of files is given below (minus directories):

```
Directory of C:\Program Files\Bullfrog\Hospital
09/08/2002  09:22            35,328 AweMan32.dll
04/06/2016  20:52            26,986 DeIsL1.isu
04/06/2016  20:51                56 Hospital.Cfg
09/08/2002  09:23         1,074,688 Hospital.exe
09/08/2002  09:23                85 Modem.ini
09/08/2002  09:23           144,384 Mss32.dll
04/06/2016  21:18             6,256 NETPLAY.TXT
04/06/2016  21:18             1,395 README.TXT
09/08/2002  09:23            71,168 Smackw32.dll
09/08/2002  09:23           109,056 WSnd7R.dll
```

The `Hospital.cfg` file does not have any interesting options. Its entire listing is:

```
INSTALL_PATH=D:\Hosp\
INSTALL_TYPE=MAX
LANGUAGE=ENG
```

An the in-game options don't offer any help either. How do I get better resolution? Even 800x600 would make the game easier to play (toug 1024x768 would be ideal).

Comment: Try installing Guest Additions from the "Devices" menu. This will load a CD from which you can run the setup.

Comment: I'm unsure what `setup` you are referring to. Guest Additions is installed, and the host CD driver has been added to the VM (from which I installed the original game). Is there an additional "setup" program on the CD?

Comment: In the past I've always solved my resolution problems like this by installing Guest Additions and restarting; you may have a different issue, in which case I'm not knowledgeable enough to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Theme Hospital is a [DOS game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_Hospital) (well, and playstation) and as such only runs on VGA resolution.

There are open source clones which support higher resolutions though I haven't tried them, for more information on that see https://www.gogwiki.com/index.php/Theme_Hospital

As a bonus of the open source clone you don't need a virtual machine anymore, or even windows.